# Difference between beta reduction and substitution

Tags: lambda-calculus

I can not see the difference between beta reduction and substitution.

For example:

```
(+ x 1) [x -> 2]
```

Here I can do the substitution, replace the variable x through 2(lambda expression) and result is:

```
(+ 2 1)
```

An example of beta reduction:

```
(λ x. + x 1) 2
```

the result would be

```
+ 2 1
```

For me, there are no difference between them, but there is a rule, I can not substitute the lambda expression, when the metavariable is bound

```
(λ x. + x 1) [x -> 2] No possible to substitute it.
```

Only free variables can be substitute it.

What is the difference between the diction:

```
(λ x. + x 1) 2
```

and

```
(λ x. + x 1) [x -> 2]
```

Comment: Note: Is `x` a metavariable?

Comment: You seem to be confusing application with substitution. Application is part of the lambda-calculus syntax, substitution is not. Substitution lives in the "math world" of the theory which defines the calculus semantics, but is not a notation which can be used by the "lambda programmer", so to speak. Perhaps confusingly, it is a _meta_ operator which modifies the syntax, so it is written next to lambda-terms to operate on them. E.g. I can define an operator $c(P)$ which given a C program $P$, returns the C program $P$ after incrementing constants in it. Then, $c$ is not part of the C language.

Comment: I did not get what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The $\beta$ reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Beta_reduction) is defined by using [capture-avoidng substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions). That is,

$$
  (\lambda x. M)N \longrightarrow_\beta M[x \mapsto N]
$$

So it's the definition. Under [the $\beta$-equivalence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/634/what-is-beta-equivalence), $(\lambda x. M)N \equiv_\beta M[x \mapsto N]$, but syntactically, $(\lambda x. M)N \neq M[x \mapsto N]$.

Note that substitution is a meta-operation on $\lambda$-calculus terms (normally).
A $\lambda$-calculus term $M$ is whether a variable $x$,
a lambda abstraction $(\lambda x. M')$, or an application $M_1 M_2$.
That's it.
There is no substitution.
Substitution is a map on $\lambda$-calculus terms.
Therefore, for example, a term $({+}~x~y)[x \mapsto z]$ is **syntactically** equal to $({+}~z~y)$.
There is no reduction.
In contrast to this, $(\lambda x. {+}~x~y)~z$ is **not** syntactically equal to $({+}~z~y)$, although it can be reduced to $({+}~x~y)$.

---

Also, $(\lambda x. {+}~x~1)~2$ is different from $(\lambda x. {+}~x~1)[x \mapsto 2]$. The latter is equal to $(\lambda x. {+}~x~1)$.

Comment: I think [@chi's comment](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69790/difference-between-beta-reduction-and-substitution/69792?noredirect=1#comment149283_69790) is very nice! Please check it too :)

Comment: Just to muddy the waters, there are [lambda calculi with explicit substitutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_substitution) for which substitution is an object language level operation (as opposed to a meta-operation). In those, a single step of $\beta$-reduction will produce an explicit substitution which is unequivocally distinct from the redex. (Note, it is *not* necessarily the case that $(\lambda x.M)N \neq M[x\mapsto N]$ in the normal (non-explicit substitution) lambda calculus, though it usually is.)

Comment: @DerekElkins Is there any variant of the λ-calculus *without* explicit substitution which treats $(\lambda x. M)N = M[x \mapsto N]$ (syntactically)? If so, I think β-reductions would be unnecessary in the calculus.

Comment: @nekketsuuu I'm not quite sure what you mean. It sounds like you want to consider two terms equal if they are $\beta$-equivalent. This would kind of defeat the point. Also as $\beta$-equivalence is undecidable, this would be awkward. But maybe [Böhm trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6hm_tree) would interest you(?)

Comment: @DerekElkins Oh I misunderstood about the last sentence of [your comment](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/69790/difference-between-beta-reduction-and-substitution/69792?noredirect=1#comment149489_69792). Thank you.